# onclick event for Imported component in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have imported a component from a different file and I want to reset my timer if I click on the imported component's elements. Is there a way to tackle this issue or should I write both components in **single jsx** ?

```
import {SampleComponent} from "../SampleComponent";
<div>
   <SampleComponent  onClick = {?????????}/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do here is,

```
import {SampleComponent} from "../SampleComponent";

<div onClick={??????}>
   <SampleComponent/>
</div>
```

Or you can pass the function from your parent component and add click event on top node of the child component.

```
<div>
   <SampleComponent onHandleClick={() => ??????}/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call a function in parent component, whenever an event (such as in your case an `onClick` event) occurs in a child component, you will need to pass the parent function as a props.
Here's what it will look like:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
 handleClick = () => { ... }

 render {
  return (
   <SampleComponent onClick={this.handleClick} />
  )
 }
}
```

And here is how your SampleComponent will be:

```
class SampleComponent extends React.Component {

 render {
  return (
   <div onClick={this.props.onClick}> //to call the function on whole component
    <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Click Me</button> //to call the function on a specific element
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

What I have understand so far from your question is that you want to call a function in SampleComponent whenever a click event occurs on it (on SampleComponent).

To do this, here is how your `SampleComponent` will look like :

```
class SampleComponent extends React.Component {
.
.
render() {
 handleClick = () => { ... }

 return (
  <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
    ...
  </div>
 )
}
```

**Note: For this you don't need to add onClick in parent.**

Answer (score 1):

```
resetTimerHandler = (timer)=>{
    timer = 0; or this.setState({timer: 0}) // how ever you are defining timer
}
render(){
    let displayTimer;
    this.updateTimer(displayTimer)// However you are updating timer
    return(
        <SampleComponent onClick={this.resetTimerHandler.bind(this,displayTimer)} />)
```

Without knowing how you are updating your timer I can't really give a specific answer but you should be able to apply this dummy code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question specifically without more context (like what timer are you wanting to reset). But the answer is *no*, you do not need to implement both components in the same file. This is fundamental to react to pass props like what you tried to do in your question.

Here is an example.
Say your `SampleComponent` looks like the following:

```
// SampleComponent.jsx

function SampleComponent({ onClick }) { // the argument is an object full of the props being passed in
  return (
    <button onClick={(event) => onClick(event)}>Click Me!</button>
  );
}
```

and the component that is using `SampleComponent` looks like this:

```
import SampleComponent from '../SampleComponent';

function resetTimer() {
  // Add logic to reset timer here
}

function TimerHandler() {
  return (
    <SampleComponent onClick={() => resetTimer()} />
  );
}
```

Now when you click the `button` rendered by `SampleComponent`, the `onClick` handler passed from `TimerHandler` will be called.

A prop on a React component is really just an argument passed into a `function` :)